# Radiation from Sticky Tape

Tags: optics, visible-light, potential-energy, physical-chemistry, home-experiment

I was pulling off some duct tape (black Gorilla tape) from the side of my stand-alone air-conditioner unit in the dark. Although stuck on well, the tape was fresh and came off cleanly from the plastic outer cover. During separation, at the point of separation, a blue light was emitted. I repeated this by adding a new piece of tape and pulling it off. Is the light energy from me pulling on the tape making light or is it the bond being broken between the tape and plastic? What is this kind of light called?

Comment: "Is the light energy from me pulling on the tape making light or is it the bond being broken between the tape and plastic?" Both. Energy from you pulling the tape is breaking bonds. It doesn't make sense to ask whether the energy is making light; there has to be *some* mechanism by which the energy produces light. Just because light is energy doesn't mean energy makes light all by itself.

Comment: More on [triboluminescence](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%20triboluminescence)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Triboluminescence. The exact mechanism in sticky stuff is still uncertain, but it's not just light. It makes X-rays. Fractoluminescence is the version that applies only to fracturing crystals (e.g. Wint-o-Green Lifesavers®).

Here's a photo from Tribogenics, the now defunct company that made portable X-ray sources:

[image]

Comment: Then it is possible to make a source of X-Ray from a single point on a tape spool. In an ideal container, like rewinding a cassette tape, could the X-Rays be directed and focused from transferring tape from one spool to another and if enough usable X-ray could be emitted?

Comment: X-rays from duct tape: macgyver physics at work.

Comment: Relevant article in New Scientist: https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn15016-humble-sticky-tape-emits-powerful-x-rays/ . Note that to generate X rays the tape needs to be in a vacuum.

Comment: Obviously cold fusion (this is sarcasm)